# Keyboard shortcuts for international characters with non-US keyboards

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I am looking on this list for typing non-English characters in Word:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-international-characters-HP005186562.aspx

I want to type Danish characters.

Some characters are OK, but I can't figure out:
å, Å    CTRL+SHIFT+@, a or A

I have an AZERTY keyboard where '@' is on the 2-key, accessed with with [ALT Gr].
Without  [ALT Gr] you get '2' or 'é', depending on the shift-key.

It is the only character I need which I can't do, but I would like to know how to do it with various West-European keyboard layouts.
(I don't want to switch keyboard layout)

Answer (score 0):

The best option, in my opinion, would be to buy a US keyboard and use the US international keyboard mapping.

I used a French layout for many years, but there's no way I'm going back to it. I'm using US international and I can type for any western language with it.

Just using plain US for programming as it's a bit faster, you have to type 2 times on the quotes with US international for example as they are used for accents.